# Find the solution of $u_{x}+u_{y}=u^{2}$ passing through $u=x$ when $y=-x$ and indicate the region in the $(x,y)$ plane where your solution is valid.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Find the solution of

$$u_{x}+u_{y}=u^{2}$$

passing through $u=x$ when $y=-x$ and indicate the region in the $(x,y)$ plane where your solution is valid.

I am current attempting this as part of exam prep. I started by parametrising the initial data.

$u_{0}(s) = s, x_{0}(s)=s, y_{0}(s)=-s$

Then writing a set of equations for characteristics:

$\frac{dx}{d\tau} = 1, \frac{dy}{d\tau} = 1, \frac{du}{d\tau} = u^{2}$

Integrating these we have:

$x=\tau + x_{0}(s), y=\tau + y_{0}(s), u=u^{2}\tau + u_{0}(s)$

That is

$x=\tau + s, y=\tau - s, u =u^{2}\tau + s$

After eliminating $\tau$ and $s$ from $u$ and using $u=x$, we have:

$u=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}(x+y)+\frac{1}{2}(x-y)$

However im not sure if what i have done is correct and where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your solution of the $u$ equation is incorrect. You can’t just integrate both sides and end up with a $\tau$ multiplier; it’s a separable equation however, so you can divide by $u^2$ and integrate the differential $du/u^2$.

Comment: So that would be $-\frac{1}{u} = \tau + u_{0}(s)$. Then $u=-\frac{1}{\tau + s}$? And then I would eliminate $\tau$ and $s$ from this equation for $u$?

Comment: Yes that’s exactly right

Comment: This gives me $u=-\frac{1}{x}$ so I assume in the $(x,y)$ plane that the solution is only valid for $x\neq 0$?

Comment: You must have made a mistake somewhere; $u=-\frac 1 x$ satisfies the equation but doesn’t satisfy the constraint $u(x,-x)=x$.

Comment: Yes after a long look I have found my mistake. It was with constants of integration and using the initial conditions. I now have $u = \frac{s}{1-s\tau}$ and when eliminating $\tau$ and $s$ I get $u = \frac{2(x-y)}{4-(x^{2}-y^{2})}$, which I believe now correctly satsifies the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In a slightly different way you get from the equations for the characteristic curves $y=x+C_1$, $\frac{du}{dx}=u^2$ so that $x+u^{-1}=C_2$ and as only one constant is free there is a function $F$ with
$$
x+u^{-1}=C_2=f(C_1)=f(y-x)
$$
and the initial condition implies 
$$
s+s^{-1}=f(-2s)\implies f(t)=-\frac t2-\frac 2t
$$
and thus
$$
u(x,y)=-\left(x+\frac{y-x}2+\frac2{y-x}\right)^{-1}=\frac{2(x-y)}{y^2-x^2+4}
$$